# No Title and Path Column in KeywordQuery in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, search

i have a SharePoint 2013 Farm and want to Query the Search and display the outputs Title and Path column. Under SP2010 i have did it successfully with the code below:

```
Dim site As SPSite = New SPSite(url)
Dim web As SPWeb = site.OpenWeb

Dim proxy As SearchServiceApplicationProxy = DirectCast(SearchServiceApplicationProxy.GetProxy(SPServiceContext.GetContext(site)), SearchServiceApplicationProxy)
Dim q As KeywordQuery = New KeywordQuery(proxy)

q.ResultsProvider = SearchProvider.Default
q.ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults
q.RowLimit = 2000

Dim path as String = "http://sp2013/sites"

Dim queryClassAndPath As String = "contentclass:""sts_site"" AND path:""" & path & """"

q.SelectProperties.Add("Title");
q.SelectProperties.Add("Path");

q.QueryText = querytext

q.TrimDuplicates = False

Dim results As ResultTableCollection = q.Execute()
Dim result As ResultTable = results(ResultType.RelevantResults)

Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
dt.Load(result, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges)

For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Console.WriteLine(r(0))
Next
```

But when i execute this against an SharePoint 2013 Search server i do not get a Title nor Path column.

Why isnt the Title and Path Column in the results anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. If you define in the KeyWordQuery Object SelectedProperties, than you get beside these Properties additional Properties so that a result via result[0] is not possible. You have to call the Property explicit by

result["Title"]